# How to use HTTP data from request to trigger JSON function?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I've set up an analog button using Arduino to communicate with Blynk cloud to provide either a O or 1 as data output on a cloud server. Data reads as ["0"] or ["1"]. At this point, my goal is to build a REST API where I can use an XML request as below to trigger another function:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest
const url='myURL';
Http.open("GET",url);
Http.send();const Http = new XMLHttpRequest
Http.send();
```

This request will output data in the aforementioned formats of 1 or 0. I'm very new to JavaScript and don't understand how to program an "if then" statement translating HTTP return data into another function. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add an event listener that runs when the response to the request is received.

Comment: Also remove the second `const Http = new XMLHttpRequest` and add `()` to the function call: `const Http = new XMLHttpRequest()` to the first one

Comment: In modern JavaScript this is easier using the `Fetch` API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: [At least RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thank you all! This is so helpful. Was looking exactly for the event listener information. Will try the fetch command, thanks Barmar.